# Visual basic ListView: How to disable auto select in first row?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I've made a listview command where I press a button and the item automatically appears in listview. The listview has 3 columns: Order list, Price list, and Quantity. I've added a button where it removes the quantity and decreases the price according to its information. I've succeeded in removing the specific quantity by selecting it and it works only with one item, but whenever more items are added, it doesn't work anymore. Thanks in advance for the help!

[The program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD540.png) : [Removing the quantity of the order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj6Qy.png) : [More items added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJUQH.png) : [The error occurs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sFWz.png)

```
    Private Sub Button15_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click

    If olqlistview.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Beep()
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else
        Dim totale As Integer, pt As Integer, tp As Integer
        Dim x As Integer = olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text, y As Integer = olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(1).SubItems(1).Text
        For i = 0 To olqlistview.SelectedItems.Count
            If i = 1 Then
                Dim lve As New ListViewItem
                totale = Val(olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text) - 1
                olqlistview.Items(0).SubItems(2).Text = CStr(totale)

                tp = Val(y) / Val(x)
                pt = Val(y) - Val(tp)

                olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text = Val(pt)
            End If
            If x = 1 And i = 1 Then
                olqlistview.Items.Remove(olqlistview.SelectedItems(0))
            End If
        Next

        Dim lv As ListViewItem
        Dim total As Long
        Dim quantitytotal As Long
        For Each lv In olqlistview.Items
            total = total + CStr(lv.SubItems(1).Text)
            quantitytotal = quantitytotal + CStr(lv.SubItems(2).Text)
        Next

        amtdue.Text = total
        Label1.Text = total
        tq.Text = quantitytotal
    End If
End Sub
    If olqlistview.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Beep()
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else
        Dim totale As Integer, pt As Integer, tp As Integer
        Dim x As Integer = olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text, y As Integer = olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(1).SubItems(1).Text
        For i = 0 To olqlistview.SelectedItems.Count
            If i = 1 Then
                Dim lve As New ListViewItem
                totale = Val(olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text) - 1
                olqlistview.Items(0).SubItems(2).Text = CStr(totale)

                tp = Val(y) / Val(x)
                pt = Val(y) - Val(tp)

                olqlistview.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text = Val(pt)
            End If
            If x = 1 And i = 1 Then
                olqlistview.Items.Remove(olqlistview.SelectedItems(0))
            End If
        Next

        Dim lv As ListViewItem
        Dim total As Long
        Dim quantitytotal As Long
        For Each lv In olqlistview.Items
            total = total + CStr(lv.SubItems(1).Text)
            quantitytotal = quantitytotal + CStr(lv.SubItems(2).Text)
        Next

        amtdue.Text = total
        Label1.Text = total
        tq.Text = quantitytotal
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time following the steps, and determining the problem vs the desired results (which are never stated).  This is what I see as the sequence

[image]

Is line 8 supposed to revert from line 4 back to line 1?  or is line 8 a typo?

What was attempted in line 10? What are the expected results?  Just saying "it doesn't work anymore" is not clear.

Comment: I apologize for not putting the desired results. The problem was that if there were more items, and I select an item (for example the 3rd row), it would always automatically select the first row and the code would proceed from the first row, rather than the selected third row. It only works if there's only 1 row of the item. My desired result would be whenever I select an item from lots of selection (for example 5th row item), the code would proceed from the 5th row instead of the 1st row item.

Comment: There is a typo in the codes. The codes below the first End Sub is just a duplication of the code